# How to start with QT?

Tags: qt4

I am new to Qt How to learn it , suggest me easy tutorials and books.
Thank you.

Comment: You've clearly not tried just searching for resources, or looked at the Qt website, so try that first.

Comment: here is the tutorial http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has a [getting started guide](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/gettingstartedqt.html), a number of [tutorials](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/tutorials.html), and many, many [examples](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/all-examples.html) scattered throughout their [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/index.html).  They even tell you [how to learn Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/how-to-learn-qt.html).  Assuming you know C++, I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Qt official documentation mentioned above I would also recommend you a book written by Jasmin Blanchette and Mark Summerfield called [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160). It is **very** useful if you just start with Qt and explains everything very good. After you more or less good Qt programmer, try [Advanced Qt Programming: Creating Great Software with C++ and Qt 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635906). Its more advanced but will help you to understand hard topics of Qt and make you much more professional in Qt. That from my own experience.

Good luck learning Qt !